# Having a error lerna success run No packages found with the lifecycle script 'typecheck'

Tags: javascript, lerna

I have a problem with starting lerna. I get an error 'lerna success run No packages found with the lifecycle script 'typecheck'. How I can fix it?
My package.json

```
{
 "name": "test-web",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "typecheck": "lerna run typecheck",
   "prepare": "lerna run prepare"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "husky": "^2.4.1",
   "lerna": "^3.22.1",
   "tslint": "^5.17.0"
 },
 "husky": {
   "hooks": {
     "pre-push": "yarn lint && yarn typecheck"
   }
 },
 "workspaces": [
   "frontend/**"
 ],
 "dependencies": {
   "@emotion/core": "^10.0.0",
   "@emotion/styled": "10.0.12",
   "@octokit/core": "^3.2.1",
   "glob": "*",
   "jest-emotion": "10.0.11",
   "prop-types": "^15.5.4",
   "react": "16.8.6",
   "react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
   "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
   "redux": "^4.0.5",
   "redux-persist": "5.10.0",
   "typescript": "^4.0.5"
 }
}
```

My lerna.json

```
{
 "npmClient": "yarn",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "packages": [
   "frontend/**"
 ],
 "useWorkspaces": true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I find the way to fix it.
Firstly, always check your local packages, it should contains local scripts. For me it's typecheck script.
Secondly, always check your devDependencies in your local scripts.
And of course always check your workspaces